# Is there an event to detect focus and blur on my window/tab

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Is there any way to detect whether the user focused my page? Or is it possible to detect whether my page is opened but not in the current tab that is focused?

Comment: This is a terrible question sorry, but there is no substance to this and I might aswell better spend my time contemplating the meaning of life!  Show some code and effort and anything better than the question above!

Comment: Simply no, you cannot. You could detect if the webpage is focussed (explained in the answers), has a mouse that hovers etc. But the browser tab switch cannot be detected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Read up**

[GlobalEventHandlers.onfocus](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onfocus)
[GlobalEventHandlers.onblur](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onblur)
[Window.focus()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/focus)

**JavaScript**

```
window.onfocus = function() { console.log('Yeah, got focus'); }
window.onblur = function() { console.log('Yeah, lost focus'); }
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/a2jjs5Lb/)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery .focusin() https://api.jquery.com/focusin/

Something like that.

```
$(window).on('focus', function() { alert("focus") });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5cLf0fn7/2/